# How to add logo to a simple CSS hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

My website has a responsive hamburger menu that uses plain HTML and CSS as I still haven't gotten into JS.

I am trying to add a logo to the menu which will float left of the menu when it is in desktop mode and centered when it jumps to the hamburger menu dropdown.

I am attaching my code below. I did not find a solution that applies to such a bare CSS/HTML solution.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
  text-align: right;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

span {
  color: #54D17A;
}

label {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: none;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menu {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #toggle:checked+.menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Responsive Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <label for="toggle">&#9776</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#">Porfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#"><span>Get in Touch</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the logo/code in your markup?

Comment: You will need to resize it horizontally to under 500px for it to be triggered as specified in the CSS media query.

Comment: There's no code for a logo or image in your markup, only the HTML entity for the hamburger menu. Please edit your post so that it comprises a [mcve]. Specifically, we need to see this logo you say you want to add. You should include at least the closest attempt you've made to accomplish your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Am glad you are learning programming and I wish you all the very best. Now lets get you solved.

First of all, understand that in your css code, this line;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
...
}
```

means anything in the tag above will only display when your screen size has a maximum width of 500px. with this understanding, we will only have to play logics with what we want to show at what time.

Now from your question, you want to show a logo at a certain point when it is a regular menu(Desktop view) and when it is mobile screen you want it to display elsewhere.

I have modified your css code to add a class called `.hide`. anywhere that class is called, at regular menu it will show but at mobile menu, it will hide. you can use that same logic to do what you want to do. am sorry my code is not exactly what you want but the idea is there.

code is in the link below. let me know if you need clarification;

https://jsfiddle.net/9rv1xwq3/1/

Comment: Hey mw509, thank you very much for your reply. It really does help me and I appreciate that you added the class and left some space for me to fill with code, which will help me learn better. I will try the solution and let you know!

Comment: sure!!! if you have any other questions, throw it up here lets solve it. Am always glad to help. and dont forget to upvote if it helps! :D

Comment: The first part of your answer is unnecessary; it explains how to do something OP's code already does.

Comment: @TylerH, 1. he said he is learning. 2. he is asking a question on something he already has in his code.

Chances are he needs understanding of what everything does since he is learning. When I started coding, there were a lot I used but did not fully understand and we all are like that when we start. We all need the details now don't we?

Comment: mw509 I appreciate the explanation and it is very thoughtful of you, I did upvote your answer but unfortunately, my meager reputation is not enough for public viewing of my votes.

Comment: @mw509 There's a difference between teaching and explaining something that OP has already shown he knows how to do. At no point has OP said "I'm not sure how media queries work or if I'm doing that part right". The question OP asked is about displaying a logo with two different alignments based on whether the media query is active or not. The very question is *predicated* on the understanding that OP knows how media queries already work.